# sweetalert2 with rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using [sweetify gem](https://github.com/Atrox/sweetify) to add sweetalert2 to my rails 6 app, but I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined
```

I added the following code to the environment.js file

```
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  sweetalert2: 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all',
  Swal: 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all'
}));
```

and I do require it in the application.js file as the following

```
require("sweetalert2")
```

the sweetify gem add the below code before the end of the  tag

```
<script>
      Swal.fire({"showConfirmButton":true,"timer":null,"allowOutsideClick":false,"confirmButtonText":"Try again","type":"error","text":"there was a problem saving your Information, please try again","title":"Oops..."})
    </script>
```

I don't know what I'm missing.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Is this rails? Sounds like you're also using react or some sort of JS framework

Comment: @Waclock This looks like Rails with the newly-default webpacker gem.

Comment: @FDI Does your webpack compile successfully? Are you able to inspect the compiled pack to see if the sweetify code made it in? You also might need to try `import { Swal } from "sweetalert2";`.

Comment: @taylorthurlow Yes the sweetalert code is there

Comment: @FDI If it's in the pack, after you load the page you should be able to use/inspect the `Swal` constant from your browser console. If it's not defined/usable in the console, then you probably need the extra import statement I used above.

Comment: @taylorthurlow I tried with no luck, also I noticed another error too I forgot to mention "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined", is it related? but $ is available?

Comment: @FDI `$` being available doesn't necessarily mean that jQuery is defined. Try seeing if `$()` is defined. Maybe post the entire contents of your `application.js`? EDIT: Just as an FYI, `$` is also the chrome command line variable, so if you're using Chrome it'll be defined even without jQuery. Like `$0` being a reference to the currently selected element in the DOM inspector.

Comment: It's available as I just selected an element and it returned the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196017/discussion-between-taylorthurlow-and-fdi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is in Rails 6.0.3

1. `yarn add sweetalert2`
2. Add following entries in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'
import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss'
window.Swal = Swal;
```

Answer (score 3):

try to do this :

```
yarn install sweetalert2
```

And

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
window.Swal = Swal;
```

Comment: in assets/stylesheets/application.scss you must add @import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2';